# User getting duplicate emails from Peoplesoft

Tags: workflow, peoplesoft

One particular user is associated with 2 roles and those 2 roles are there in Workflow email list and so the user gets the same email twice. Is there anyway I could avoid this duplicate emails

Thanks

Gautham

Answer (score 1):

Only a little late... :/ but saw the question so thought i'd give my 2 cents and hope this helps someone.

One option is to create dynamic 'shell' roles to drive your work flow. This way you can use queries on the roles users have and build your work flow roles separate from security roles.

The first query can look for the multiple roles and others look for singular, excluding the multiple.